# Creating a Django admin account: null value of password

Tags: django

In a Django project, I have the following script to create an `admin` account:

```
User.objects.all().delete()
admin = User()
admin.username = 'admin'
admin.password = admin.set_password('admin')
admin.save()
```

But I got the error message:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password):

> set_password(raw_password):
>      Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing.

It sets the password for you, and then returns `None`, so don't assign it back to `user.password`. In other words, just do:

```
admin.username = 'admin'
admin.set_password('admin')
admin.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

`.set_password()` already sets the password of the given user, so doesn't return anything. Thus, you should just do:

```
>>> admin.set_password('admin')
>>> admin.save()
```

Assuming you want to create a user that will have permission for everything, why don't you use [`.create_superuser()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser) instead:

```
>>> User.objects.create_superuser(username="admin", password="admin", email=None)
```

so you don't have to manually set `.is_superuser` and `.is_staff` to `True`.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot.